# Troubleshoot a very slow system performance (Kubuntu, intel graphics)

Tags: performance, cpu, kubuntu

The performance of my laptop is simply terrible. 
i3 M380 @ 2.53GHz, 4GB RAM (of which more than 2GB is rarely used), intel HD graphics (to external monitor through HDMI). 
It takes 70s for the Inkscape to load, 65s for Chrome+GMail, 720p video is unwatchable and even SD video is sometimes choppy. I sometimes have to wait >30s for a more demanding web pages to render. Even google search page is very slow.
Flash video is extremely choppy.

I am used to having gkrellm system monitor on-screen all the time so can definitely say that it seems like the CPU is the bottleneck (100% on one or more virtual cores). I also have 'top' plugin running so can see that no background process is misbehaving. My system idles <%5 CPU usage. 
CPU seems to be scaling correctly (2.53GHz on high load). It's not the video drivers (Intel graphics should be well supported and I have direct rendering). Disk (SMART) reports no errors and hdparm speed test seems normal. Memtest also reports no errors.

A complete system reinstall from 12.04 to 14.04 didn't help. 
Any idea what I could try?

Comment: what filesystem and how full?

Comment: ext4 and currently quite full but the performance was the same even with 50% free. Even the things that should not be disk intensive seem slow.